# unrecognized chrome option: prefs

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Есть вот такой код на python. Если не разбивать на разные Options: *prefs* и *debuggerAddress*, то получаю ошибку `unrecognized chrome option: prefs`, а если разбить то `chrome_options` с prefs - не работают.

````
    chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", f"127.0.0.1:{response.json()['automation']['port']}")

    #что то думать с этим
    prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1, "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(executable_path='chromedriver.exe'), chrome_options=options, options=chrome_options)```
selenium==4.2.0
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64960630/16290737

Comment: @ArthurLangley-Reddle `options = ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1, "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1}
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", f"127.0.0.1:{response.json()['automation']['port']}")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(executable_path='chromedriver.exe'), options=options, service_log_path='NUL')` Исправил, но ошибка осталась